# Javascript object destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Why is this not valid when using the new es6 destructuring syntax

```
var a, b, c;
{a, b, c } = {a:1, b:2, c:3};
```

when this is:

```
var {a, b, c } = {a:1, b:2, c:3};
console.log(a, ' ', b, ' ',c);
```

and so is this:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 3;

[a, b] = [b, a];
```

I had a read of [the MDN documentataion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and I see no mention of the syntax I'm attempting and I assume there must be a good reason, I'm just trying to understand why.

Comment: To me the MDN documentation implies that you *can* do what you were attempting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, the first `{` is ambiguous and the parser will interpret it as the beginning of a **block**. While `{a, b, c}` is a valid block, the following assignment operator is not valid.

Wrap everything in parenthesis and it will parse correctly:

```
({a, b, c} = {a:1, b:2, c:3});
```

[**Example**](http://felix-kling.de/esprima_ast_explorer/#/sAtgbz4r18/1)

---

This is similar to having an object literal by itself (for whatever reasons):

```
{"a": 42}   // parse error
({"a": 42}) // works
```

Comment: With traceur I get `Invalid left-hand side in assignment` when doing that. `({a, b, c} = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3});` works for me.

Comment: @JMM: Yeah, I had that before, but esprima is parsing the my case correctly. I actually don't know what's correct. I guess wrapping everything in parenthesis is safer (updated).

Comment: Ok, I thought you did, then I looked again and it was different but didn't show an edit -- I guess it does that when an edit happens before a certain timeout. It's worth noting that the MDN article @Raoul linked to implies that you can do just what he was trying to do.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't look at the article. I don't know if it is supposed to work at some point, I guess it depends on the parser.

Comment: Aha, that makes complete sense, I was so busy thinking about the new syntax I forgot to think about basic parsing rules :)  This works perfectly in 6to5 also.  Thanks.