# Why does an object literal get ignored in a statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I was messing around the JavaScript console and noticed that

```
>> {}[1]
[1]
```

evaluates as an array. After some more messing around I found that

```
>> b = {}[1]
undefined
```

gives me the expected result of undefined. At first I thought the curly braces were being interpreted as a block, but attempting

```
>> {a:1}[1]
[1]
```

still gave me the the `[1]` array. I would expect that if it was interpreted as a block, it would result in a syntax error. Why is this the case?

**More Info**: I discovered from [Don't understand why you should not use an object literal at the beginning of a statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997647), that it likely is a block, but this does not answer how this is not a syntax error unless it is doing a lookahead to determine if it's an object literal or a block, but it's not an object literal because it's still evaluating to `[1]`.

**EDIT**: I tried this in Chrome and Firefox in their debugging consoles and Node.js's command line interface.

Comment: Javascript is weird... this is worth watching-  [link] (https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) (javascript starts at 1:20)

Comment: I feel like you've answered your own question. It's interpreted as a block in this case. You could do `{}"hello"` and it would return `"hello"`. However, if you try to store this value in a variable, then you will get your errors thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would expect that if it was interpreted as a block, it would result in a syntax error. Why is this the case?

Inside a block, an expression consisting of a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) followed by a [number literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Integers) is valid.

> but this does not answer how this is not a syntax error unless it is doing a lookahead to determine if it's an object literal or a block

It doesn't need to look ahead. It is a block because of what is on the left hand side of the `{` (i.e. nothing).